# How do I isolate an image from the html so that I can edit where it goes on the website?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to doing html and I don't know how you could isolate an image so that it doesn't get affected by the img code of the CSS. I tried using

```html
<a href="hello.png"><img src="images/hello.png" height="100" width="350"/></a>
<a href="hello.png"><"div id=img2" src="images/hello.png" height="100" width="350"/></a>
```

(I created a css which is called #img2) kind of thing but it doesn't really work for some reason.

Comment: ...you tried using???

Comment: its like this
 <a href="hello.png"><img src="images/hello.png" height="100" width="350"/></a>
I tried doing this: <a href="hello.png"><div id="img2" src="images/hello.png" height="100" width="350"/></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have

```
<a href="hello.png"><img src="images/hello.png" height="100" width="350"/></a>
```

and wish to control its style using CSS, ensuring that it doesn't get styled by the img style in a referenced css file/block

1. add an id to the img tag

   ...
       img id="myimage" src="images/hello.png" height="100" width="350"/>
       /a>
2. create a style to target your id:

   img#myimage{
           /*put styles in here to overide img styles*/
           }

With css, more specific matches will override less specific matches (ie img#myimage trumps image) with the exception that !important will trump a better match. If your img style has !important you need to add it to your img#myimage style